# Effort applied on the cement silo

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, prestressed-concrete

As mentioned in the question above, I am working on a clinker silo, I want to know if the forces applied on the cone of the silo are exclusively coming from the weight of the material stocked or their any other source that I need to consider specifically in the emptying phase.

I stay available for any information required for you to answer my question.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a ['Naive design' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/188/1832). Such questions are excessively broad and are therefore not a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. I edited the question in the purpose of making it more targeted, I hope that met that purpose.

Comment: Construction, environmental, dynamic loads may all be relevant. You would need to provide a lot more details about the design, location, etc for this to be answerable. If you search for 'Clinker Silo Design' you will find several design reports which may be a useful starting point.

Comment: By "cone" I'm assuming you mean the "funnel" at the base of a silo: some silo structures have cone roofs. Then again, there is also the cone formed by the material in the silo as it drawn out of the silo. One thing to consider is that for some materials in silos a zone of material around the walls of the silo can form, through which the material cone forms. Depending on the design of the silo the "dead" material on the walls will add weight to the foundations of the silo, not necessarily the cone in the base of the structure.

Comment: Thank you for you answers mg4w I will look through the different reports. Absolutely Fred I agree with you, the current silo that I have is known as central cone silo, the dead material is present beside the walls on a beam called ring beam that I took into consideration.